# Truncate left end of string in java.util.logging.logger?

Tags: java.util.logging

Using the java.util.logging.logger.simpleformatter.format, is there a way to get only the last number of characters from a string?  For example, the source is com.my.package.name.my.class.name.  I want to use precision to get the least significant 20 characters as in e.name.my.class.name.  Is there a way to specify this in a format string?

I've been working with the following, but haven't been able to get it to work for the bolded entries:

-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS **%4$.15s** %2$8s %5$s%6$s%n"

I have been able to use log4j successfully and can go that route if necessary, but am trying to eliminate unnecessary packages.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the custom formatting for the SimpleFormatter is provided by the [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.  Per that documentation:

> The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the output. ... For general argument types, the precision is the maximum number of characters to be written to the output.

There is no concept of substrings from the left or right.  It would be nice if a negative precision was defined as maximum number of characters from the right and positive precision was maximum number of characters from the left.

Your only workaround would be to find a 3rd party java.util.logging.Formatter or create your own java.util.logging.Formatter to meet your needs.

Comment: That's what I was figuring would be the case.  The doc talks about padding for width, but is pretty silent on truncation.  Looks like log4j will have to stay in the mix.

Comment: I would imagine that there are some ports of the log4j pattern layout to j.u.l.  In java.util.logging world this would be called PatternFormatter.  You might want to do some searching.